# How to auto replace past seconds/ minutes/ hours with current time in a clock application

Tags: javascript, html, css, clock

I'm trying to display the current time, however with the passing of each second, a new instance of the time is added to the div.

How can the current time replace the past times?

I've tried to use a replace function, set the textContent to that replace function, but had no success. I'm confused because as you can see, the code that makes the analog clock reloads each second with the correct time and am not sure why this is not the case for designing the digital clock portion.

```js
const secondHand = document.querySelector('.second-hand')
const minuteHand = document.querySelector('.min-hand')
const hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour-hand')

// analog clock
function setAnalogClock() {
    const now = new Date()

    //get seconds
    const secs = now.getSeconds()
    const secDegs = ((secs / 60) * 360) + 90
    secondHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secDegs}deg)`

    //get minutes
    const mins = now.getMinutes()
    const minDegs = ((mins / 60) * 360) + 90
    minuteHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minDegs}deg)`

    //get hours
    const hours = now.getHours()
    const hourDeg = ((hours / 12) * 360) + 90
    hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDeg}deg)`

}

setInterval(setAnalogClock, 1000)

function setDigitalClock() {
    const digitalSec = document.querySelector('.sec')
    const digitalMin = document.querySelector('.min')
    const digitalHour = document.querySelector('.hour')

    const now = new Date()

    // set seconds
    const secTxt = document.createElement('span')
    secTxt.textContent = now.getSeconds()
    digitalSec.appendChild(secTxt)

    // set minutes
    const minTxt = document.createElement('span')
    minTxt.textContent = now.getMinutes()
    digitalMin.appendChild(minTxt)

    // set hours
    const hourTxt = document.createElement('span')
    hourTxt.textContent = now.getHours()
    digitalHour.appendChild(hourTxt)
}

setInterval(setDigitalClock, 1000)
```

```css
html {
  background: rgb(237, 245, 250);
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'helvetica neue';
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.digital{
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.clock {
  width: 30rem;
  height: 30rem;
  border: 20px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.clock-face {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-3px);
  /* account for the height of the clock hands */
}

.hand,
.dot {
  width: 50%;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100%;
  transform: rotate: 90(90deg);
  transition: all .05s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.1, 2.7, .58, 1)
}

.second-hand {
  background: blue;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.min-hand {
  background: yellow;
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.hour-hand {
  background: red;
}

.dot {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-left: 47%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>JS + CSS Clock</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="digital">
        <div class="sec"></div>
        <div class="min"></div>
        <div class="hour"></div>
    </div>

  <div class="clock">
    <div class="clock-face">
      <div class="hand hour-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand min-hand"></div>
      <div class="hand second-hand"></div>
      <div class="dot"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="/app.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending span elements each time you call setDigitalClock().

The easiest and most efficient way is not to even append at all.

```
  digitalSec.innerText = now.getSeconds();
  digitalMin.innerText = now.getMinutes();
  digitalHour.innerText = now.getHours();
```

This is simpler and isn't adding and removing elements every second which is expensive. 
Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/blacy1551/pen/qzgMxo) as well

Answer (score 1):

```
function setDigitalClock() {

    const now = new Date()
    document.querySelector(".sec").innerText = `${now.getSeconds()}`;
    document.querySelector(".min").innerText = `${now.getMinutes()}`;
    document.querySelector(".hour").innerText = `${now.getHours()}`;
}
```

Edited: as the comment below suggests.

This should do what you need to do.

Comment: `document.querySelector(".sec")` will get just one node, so you don't have to dereference with `[0]`, and since you're just setting plain text in the node you can use `.innerText` which is "cheaper" than `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, is that every time you are appending 3 new nodes to your digital clock.

What you should do, is remove the previous content, and then append the new node.

ie. instead of `digitalSec.appendChild(secTxt)`
you should do

```
digitalSec.innerHTML = ''
digitalSec.appendChild(secTxt)
```

and the same for minutes and hours.

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/dordasal/pen/jjdvmE) that works as mentioned.

You can also replace the whole

```js
    // set seconds
    const secTxt = document.createElement('span')
    secTxt.textContent = now.getSeconds()
    digitalSec.innerHTML = ''
    digitalSec.appendChild(secTxt)

    // set minutes
    const minTxt = document.createElement('span')
    minTxt.textContent = now.getMinutes()
    digitalMin.innerHTML = ''
    digitalMin.appendChild(minTxt)

    // set hours
    const hourTxt = document.createElement('span')
    hourTxt.textContent = now.getHours()
    digitalHour.innerHTML = ''
    digitalHour.appendChild(hourTxt)
```

with the following (if you don't care about that extra span)

```js
    // set seconds
    digitalSec.innerHTML = now.getSeconds()

    // set minutes
    digitalMin.innerHTML = now.getMinutes()

    // set hours
    digitalHour.innerHTML = now.getHours()
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be something like that:

```js
function clock () {
  // set variables for the clock:
  var currentTime = new Date ();
  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ();
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ();
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ();

  // add leading zeros,
  currentHours = ( currentHours < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentHours;
  currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
  currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;
  
  var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds;   // put it all together 
  document.getElementById("clock").textContent = currentTimeString;   // Update display
}
window.addEventListener('load', function() {setInterval('clock()', 1000) }); // activate the clock;
```

```html
<span id="clock"></span>
```